# XAML: Style ControlTemplate storyboard animation won't play, but trigger IS hit

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, storyboard, styles

I have a button style which I'm currently making. I want to trigger a smooth animation when the user clicks on the button. I need the two rectangle to be contained within the ControlTemplate as shown below.

The idea is that upon pressing the button, one of the rectangles fades out, and upon releasing it fades back in.

The triggers ARE being hit. I can prove this by adding a simple colour change for the buttons by doing the following before the Trigger.EnterActions:

```
<Setter TargetName="BackgroundNormal" Property="Fill" Value="Cyan" />
```

The storyboards seem not to trigger at all regardless of their content.

What am I doing wrong, please?

```
<Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextParagraphWhiteP1}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Gradient_Playback_ButtonBase}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundDepressed" Fill="Magenta" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundNormal" Fill="{DynamicResource Gradient_Playback_ButtonBase}" />

                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <Storyboard x:Key="PressDown">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundNormal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Release">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundNormal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.35" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource PressDown}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="false">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Release}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Button Visual States](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates).

Comment: @Clemens This did the trick! Many thanks!

Comment: @Clemens I just don't understand why; given that there was no error, the trigger fired and the items referenced in the storyboards were in scope: the storyboard didn't play. This seems bizarre to me.

Comment: Maybe the TargetName can't be resolved from inside the Resources section. Try to move the Storyboards into `<BeginStoryboard>...</BeginStoryboard>`.